# How to write std::bind with constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming

EDIT: I understand I could create a named function to solve the problem. I just want to learn some arcane C++ template syntax from you gurus.

---

Given this setup (the vector is guaranteed to be initially empty)

```
typedef vector<list<int>> V;
V v;
```

I want to create a partial application like this:

```
auto f = [&v](int value) { v.push_back(list<int> { value }); };
```

Unfortunately, in our working environment, we can't use lambda (with gcc 4.4). Can anyone help me writing an equivalent version using `std::bind`?

So far I come up with several attempts (using Visual Studio):

1.

```
auto f = bind<void (V::*)(const V::value_type&)>(&V::push_back, &v, list<int>(1, placeholders::_1));
```

with error

```
'<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::list<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
```

2.

```
auto f = bind<void (V::*)(const V::value_type&)>(&V::push_back, &v, list<int>::list(1, placeholders::_1));
```

with error

```
'std::list<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::list': none of the 10 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

3.

```
auto f = bind<void (V::*)(const V::value_type&)>(&V::push_back, &v, list<int> { placeholders::_1 });
```

with error

```
'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::list<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
```

4.

```
auto f = bind<void (V::*)(const V::value_type&)>(&V::push_back, &v, list<int> { (const int&) placeholders::_1 });
```

this compiles, but the vector created by `f(10)` would have a list with the first element equals to 0, not 10. It looks like the list is a default created one.

Comment: Why does it need to be `std::bind`? Why not just write a local class yourself?

Comment: Is there other way to do partial application?

Comment: @crend lambdas are just anonymous class objects.  Translation is mechanical...

Comment: I understand. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: seems like a dupe of [How do I bind arguments to a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369988/how-do-i-bind-arguments-to-a-constructor)

Comment: Why is dupe of that? There is no constructor/destructor in this question.