# How do I bind arguments to a constructor?

Tags: c++, stdbind

As described above, I want to use `std::bind` to create a function that, when called, returns an object built with a constructor with default parameters like below:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class X
{
    int x_, y_;
    public:
    X(int x, int y): x_(x), y_(y)
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    auto fun = std::bind(&X::X, 1, 2);
    X x = fun();   
}
```

Instead I get the following compiler errors:

> error: qualified reference to 'X' is a constructor name rather than a type in this context
>
> error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
>   In reference to this line:

```cpp
auto fun = std::bind(&X::X, 1, 2);
```

Comment: C++ does not allow to have a pointer to constructor.

Comment: first argument to `std::bind` should be callable object and constructor is not that.

Comment: The constructors (and the destructors) are "special". In particular, you can't call them, and they don't have names so you can't even refer to them..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments answer this question. Apparently `std::bind` cannot be used with constructors and destructors because they can't have their address taken. Thank you to Eugene, The Philomath, and molbdnilo.

Comment: Instead you could make a free function that forwards to the constructor

Comment: @M.M or a lambda `const auto fun = []() { return X{ 1, 2 }; };`